# jQuery loop appending, whether rest is day or disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

in the loop if only one is `data-name="disabled"`, then add to the rest attribute id, whether it is day or disabled rest, any idea why?

For Ex:

```
<span data-name="day"></span>
<span data-name="day"></span>
<span data-name="disabled"></span>
<span data-name="day"></span>
<span data-name="day"></span>
<span data-name="day"></span>

<span data-name="day"></span>

for (i = 1; i <= $('span').length; i++) {
  if($('span').attr('data-name') == 'disabled'){
    $('span').attr('data-name', 'disabled-day'); 
// I want superseded data-name="disabled" to all data-name="day" after `data-name="disabled"`
  }
}
```

Should I Use of for loop.

I want this result after end loop:

```
<span data-name="day"></span>
<span data-name="day"></span>
<span data-name="disabled"></span>
<span data-name="disabled"></span>
<span data-name="disabled"></span>
<span data-name="disabled"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, i hope you got the idea.

```
var temp = false;

$('span').each(function(){
  if(temp){
    $(this).attr('data-name', 'disabled');
  }
  if($(this).attr('data-name') == 'disabled'){
    temp = true;
  }      
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var found = false;
$('span').each(function() {
  if (found) {
    $(this).attr('data-name', 'disabled');
    return true
  }
  if ($(this).attr('data-name') == 'disabled') {
    found = true
  }
});

console.log($('body').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-name="day"></span>
<span data-name="day"></span>
<span data-name="disabled"></span>
<span data-name="day"></span>
<span data-name="day"></span>
<span data-name="day"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the index of found element with `disabled` attribute and just apply the same attribute to every element with higher index.

```js
var num = $('span').index($('span[data-name="disabled"]'));
  
$('span').each(function(i) {
  if (i >= num) {
    $(this).attr('data-name', 'disabled');
  }
})

console.log($('span').get());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-name="day"></span>
<span data-name="day"></span>
<span data-name="disabled"></span>
<span data-name="day"></span>
<span data-name="day"></span>
<span data-name="day"></span>
<span data-name="day"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
var disabled = false;
$('span').each(function(){
  if(disabled){
    $(this).attr('data-name', 'disabled');
    $(this).text('disabled');
  }
  if($(this).attr('data-name') == 'disabled'){
    disabled = true;
  }      
})
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-name="day">day</span>
<span data-name="day">day</span>
<span data-name="disabled">disabled</span>
<span data-name="day">day</span>
<span data-name="day">day</span>
<span data-name="day">day</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple selector that select the `span` with the `data-name="disabled"` attribute, and then use `nextAll` to select all the next siblings with `data-name="day"` attribute, and change their attribute to **disabled**:

```
$('span[data-name="disabled"]').nextAll('span[data-name="day"]').attr('data-name', 'disabled');
```

This is a working example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('span[data-name="disabled"]').nextAll('span[data-name="day"]').attr('data-name', 'disabled');
});
```

```css
[data-name="day"] { color: green; }
[data-name="disabled"] { color: red; }
[data-name="other"] { color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-name="day">1</span>
<span data-name="day">2</span>
<span data-name="disabled">3</span>
<span data-name="day">4</span>
<span data-name="day">5</span>
<span data-name="day">6</span>
<span data-name="disabled">7</span>
<span data-name="day">8</span>
<span data-name="day">9</span>
<span data-name="other">10</span>
```